# How to wait for a promise inside a loop and promise function

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I'm trying to wait for a multi promises inside a loop. This loop must turn 3 times sending 3 pieces of products array. The two initial loops will send 1000 products each and the third will send 500.

The fact is that function are ignoring the third turn and not sending it to database, just 2000 products was added as you can see in that log

[image]

My method

```
const MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE = 1000
export const addProducts = (products) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(products.length / MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE); i += 1) {
      const indexToStartExtraction = i * MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
      const sizeOfExtraction = indexToStartExtraction + MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
      const extractedProducts = products.slice(indexToStartExtraction, sizeOfExtraction);
      const ref = firebase.ref('products');
      const normalizedPostData = arrayToJsonObjectWithUid({ products: extractedProducts, ref });

      console.log(extractedProducts.length);

      ref.update(normalizedPostData).then(() => {
        console.log(`Doing ${i} call`);
        resolve(true);
      })
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
    }
  },
);
```

I've tryed to do it without success:

```
export const addProducts = (products) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    const promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(products.length / MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE); i += 1) {
      const indexToStartExtraction = i * MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
      const sizeOfExtraction = indexToStartExtraction + MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
      const extractedProducts = products.slice(indexToStartExtraction, sizeOfExtraction);
      const ref = firebase.ref('products');
      const normalizedPostData = arrayToJsonObjectWithUid({ products: extractedProducts, ref });

      console.log(extractedProducts.length);

      promises.push(ref.update(normalizedPostData));
    }
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(() => resolve())
      .catch(() => reject());
  },
);
```

How can I wait for each promise correctly?

Comment: Basically, you can't wait in a loop of a synchronous function, but you can chain promises that do API calls and promises that resolve after a particular time, and have an async function that does what you want.

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but I would recommend you chunk your array rather than the way you're doing your for-loop here. [lodash has a chunk function](https://lodash.com/docs/). What this does, is if you give it an array of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, and tell it to chunk it into 3s, it will give you back `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]`, and then you can iterate over the chunked array with your elements grouped into arrays of the appropriate size.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: *"...without breaking the rules of eslint..."* The `no-await-in-loops` is **not** one of the "recommended" rules, as you can see from the [rule list](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/). If you read [rule documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop), it specifically says that its trying to protect you from **inadvertently** doing operations in series instead of in parallel. Since you want to do the operations in series (as I understand the question), that rule doesn't apply. If you have an unusual ruleset that enables it, use a code comment to disable it for this code.

Comment: Just for clarity: Do you want to run those updates in parallel (all running at once) or in series (one running after another)? Your existing code with `Promise.all` should work correctly if you want them to run in parallel. You do, of course, have to wait for the promise from `addProducts` to settle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My understanding is that you want to run these in series.** Your current code with `Promise.all` would run them in parallel.

If you want to run them in series, the easiest away (since you're using Node.js) is to use an `async` function and `await`:

```
const MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE = 1000
export const addProducts = async (products) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(products.length / MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE); i += 1) {
    const indexToStartExtraction = i * MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
    const sizeOfExtraction = indexToStartExtraction + MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
    const extractedProducts = products.slice(indexToStartExtraction, sizeOfExtraction);
    const ref = firebase.ref('products');
    const normalizedPostData = arrayToJsonObjectWithUid({ products: extractedProducts, ref });

    console.log(extractedProducts.length);

    console.log(`Doing ${i} call`);
    await ref.update(normalizedPostData);
  }
  return true;
};
```

Any vaguely-recent version of Node.js supports `async` functions.

That function returns a promise that will:

- Reject if any of the `ref.update` calls rejects, or
- Fulfill with the value `true` when all of them have completed successfully

It waits for each to finish before starting the next. In contrast, your version with `Promise.all` starts all the updates, lets those updates run concurrently, then waits until they're all finished.

Note that whatever is calling `addProducts` will need to wait for its promise to settle, unless whatever comes after the `addProducts` call can run concurrently with the update calls `addProducts` starts.

Comment: When I do it I've got this warn from eslint: Unexpected `await` inside a loop.eslint(no-await-in-loop). I want to do it without broken eslint rules

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros - ESLint's rules are not set in stone, and `no-await-in-loop` is not one of their recommend rules (e.g.: normally it's turned off). If you want to do these calls in series (not parallel), using `await` in a loop in an `async` function is absolutely fine.

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros - In fact, if you read the [rule documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop), it says the reason for the rule is so you get parallel operations. Since your goal is to *avoid* parallel operations...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use `await` as all requests are independent of each other and can be run in parallel, therefore your second example should be the best route.

This is a snippet of a simple for loop making asynchronous actions:

```js
function someAsyncFn (i) {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  }, 100))
}

const promises = []
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  promises.push(someAsyncFn(i))
}

Promise.all(promises)
```

Notice how it yields the correct values after execution

Now we want the same thing but applied to your codebase:

```
function addProducts (products) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      const promises = [];
      const ref = firebase.ref('products');
      const max = Math.ceil(products.length / MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE)

      for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        const indexToStartExtraction = i * MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
        const sizeOfExtraction = indexToStartExtraction + MAXIMUM_POST_SIZE;
        const extractedProducts = products.slice(indexToStartExtraction, sizeOfExtraction);
        const normalizedPostData = arrayToJsonObjectWithUid({ products: extractedProducts, ref });
        promises.push(ref.update(normalizedPostData));
      }

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    },
  );
}
```

I made some cleanup but the idea is the same, can you try this code and see if it yields the correct result?

Comment: The OP's code **already** does that, runs the updates in parallel. Apparently he doesn't want to do that.

Comment: Then we would need to know what error he was getting. Reading through his code, it looks fine. It's just saying to do what he's already doing isn't really all that helpful.